# Show a notice when comment has been edited since the page was loaded

Tags: feature-request, comments, live-refresh, comment-replies

When I see a comment that I don't quite understand or don't agree with, sometimes I'll want to reply asking for clarification; but since I can't see whether a user edited their comment in the interim, sometimes my comment will be redundant by the time is published.

We don't receive a "live" notice that a comment has been updated since the page was loaded, like it is the case on posts with the hint:

> "An edit has been made to this post"

For example, on a question:

> [image]

An similar update notice for comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Given the short amount of time a comment is allowed to be edited before it locks... how often does this happen to you?

Comment: @CindyMeister Sorry for the delay. Surprisingly, Quite often. Imagine the following case: Somebody is posting a huge comment. To hint at something important, he/she want to do the post of the crucial hint without any delay even if he/she wants to enlarge the comment. So, the first part of the comment is already posted but the comment is not fulfilled. If I now see this comment and want to reply for clarification I do not have any notification if the comment was edited in the meantime if I did not refreshed the page.

Answer (score 2):

Comments aren't refreshed or updated automatically. They're reloaded after a user reloads the page, or clicks the link to see more comments.

Because of this, the page doesn't know that a comment has been edited, until you refresh the page, so a banner like we see with questions or answers can't be shown.

Adding websockets traffic or something similar open for all comments on all sites seems like a significant load, and is very likely to have factored into comments not auto-refreshing. Now, this is an assumption on my end, but I think a likely one.

Comment: The websocket is already open and will notify you about changes to the question. It probably wouldn't be a significant change to also push events about edited comments through the same open socket. On the backend that's just one more trigger. There's also an already existing event for *new* comments. (Obviously I'm armchair sys-adminning here…)

Comment: @deceze: slightly updated my answer. It was mostly the added traffic / calls / triggers that make me think it might be too much load.